# change transition shared element on activity exit

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have a recycler view containing some images and when i click on an image it opens a new activity with a view pager to show those images.

this openning contains a shared element transition. now when press the back button i want to change the transiting view to the currently viewing image.
how can i do this

I already tried `setExitSharedElementCallback` on the first activity which updates `List<String> names` and `Map<String, View> sharedElements`  on `onMapSharedElements` to appropriate ones. but still no transition happens.

is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

after more works i find out that i should also add

```
   setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
 // update names and sharedElements
        }
    }
```

to the second activity to update its transition views.

Comment: What scope do you put this function in? When I have it registered in the OnCreate of the activity that the transition returns to, it never gets called.